# html5 validation are not working on iphone

Tags: php, jquery, ios, iphone, html

**My html 5 validations are not working on i-phone please suggest. 
I am using required in my input fields.**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimated_budget" placeholder="Estimated Budget" name="estimated_budget" required = "true">
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimated_budget" placeholder="Estimated Budget" name="estimated_budget" required = "required">
```

Comment: it's specified as: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimated_budget" placeholder="Estimated Budget" name="estimated_budget" required>` without a value
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required